# Why won't Xcode 4.2 support a second-generation iPod Touch, running iOS 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, ios-4.2

I recently upgraded to Xcode 4.2, for SDK 5.0 support, but since I've done so, one of my testers, who has an iPod Touch 2nd generation running iOS 4.2.1, can't use my ad-hocs

My target is setup for Base SDK: 5.0 (Latest Version) and Deployment Target 3.2, so that should allow it. I'm also pretty sure on the tester's iOS version, as it's registered with testflightapp.

The error he's seeing is approximately this: "your device is running 4.2.1 which is less than the required version (4.3) for this build"

I notice also that I Only see versions 4.3 and 5.0 in my schemes nowadays. Is there something that should be adjusted there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Xcode Preferences -> Downloads and install 4.0-4.1 support.  You should be able to support < 4.3 then.

Comment: Clearly time to pull my minimum up to at least 4.0, if they make it this hard. Thanks.